# How can I insert data into the database when an entity is created?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating a website for a school project which uses spring for the backend. I'm trying to insert data into the database when new data is saved to a specific table.

I've tried using @HandleAfterCreate and @PrePersist, but neither worked. I'm not very experienced with spring. The teacher told us to use it and now I don't know what do.

```java
@HandleAfterCreate
public void handlePersonBeforeCreate(Person person){
    logger.info("Inside Person Before Create....");
    Set<Qualifikation> qualifikationen = new HashSet<>();
    kompetenzRepository.findAll().forEach(kompetenz -> {
        Qualifikation qualifikation = new Qualifikation();
        qualifikation.setAusmass(0);
        qualifikation.setKompetenz(kompetenz);
        qualifikation.setPerson(person);
    });
    person.setQualifikationen(qualifikationen);
    System.out.println(person.getDisplayName());
}
```

The code should set a person's "Qualifikation" to a default value when the person is inserted (via OAuth login). It should have every "Kompetenz" with a value of 0 by default. Kompetenz has a 1 to n relation to Qualifikation. If you need more information please ask me.

Comment: Can you see that log row?

Comment: @pirho The Problem is it's not even showing up. I put it in a class with `@RepositoryEventHandler` which is called in a `@Configuration` class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to have access to the repository layer of your application inside an entity. This is generally not a good idea, as the entities should only know about the data they hold, not the other application components.

In this particular case it would be wise to use a `@Service` class with a method that you can call to insert the data into the database. In the method you could then insert any other entities as well. Let your repositories be fields of the service and make them `@Autowired`.

Comment: I annotated the class with `@Service` and it logs `Hibernate: insert into person (id, version, display_name, projekt_id, role, username) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, but it's not actually inserted. Do I have to register the service or something?

Comment: Is the `handlePersonBeforeCreate` inside the `Person` entity? If so, create a new class, name it `PersonService` and annotate the class with `@Service`. Could you also post your entity, so we can see which side is the owning side of the relation?

Comment: It's in the Class annotated with `@Service`. Here is the Person Entity: [link](https://pastebin.com/8R9DBWFU) and here the Service: [link](https://pastebin.com/wQAStEZ6)

Comment: Ah, from what I can tell, `Qualifikation` is the owning side of the relation `Person` and `Qualifikation`. This means you will have to safe the `Qualifikation` via a `QualifikationRepository`.  Also `@HandleBeforeCreate` does not work on classes that are not annotated with `@RepositoryEventHandler` 
 (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-events). You should call `handlePersonBeforeCreate` manually if you want to insert a `Person`.

Comment: I added code to save the `Qualifikation` to the repository in the loop of adding them to the person. I tried the tutorial with `@RepositoryEventHandler` before but the method didn't get called. How do i call the method manually and where? Do i call it in the Entity of Person in `@PrePersist`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable **JPA auditing** . It can be enabled in Spring by add `@EnableJpaAuditing` to your persistence configuration. This tells Spring to listen JPA entity lifecycle events and call the annotated methods in appropriate places.

Also I think you should make the callback method **private** if it is meant to be called only when persisted (`@PrePersist`).

See details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa). In this article is also presented entity listeners which might also be a good solution when dealing with multiple entities having a need for same pre-persist functionality.

Comment: I already tried using `@PrePersist` but the Problem is that I want to loop though all `Kompetenz` in the Database and make `Qualifikation` out of it. I can't use `@Autowired` on the `KompetenzRepository` in the Entity though.

Comment: @Setscha but do you see the log row?

Comment: I didn't log anything in the `@PrePersist` but I know that it's generally working because i used it in an other Entity to set the relations null which works because I don't have to autowire a repository. But from the code in my question i can't see the row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a service class, a repository class and an entity which will be stored through repository. The logic of getting all inner elements and filling it with default value is to be written in service and not a good idea to write in entity class.
If you need any help regarding it, let me know .
Welcome to community!!